# VueJS how to append div inside v-html directive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following `HTML`:

```
<div v-html="parse(message.message)">
   <i v-if="message.messageTypeId === 2" class="SpecialIcon"></i>
</div>
```

For some reason the element `<i v-if="message.messageTypeId === 2"></i>` is not being added into the DOM because what I think is that when `v-html` is evaluated the `innerHTML` is being replaced.

> Any clue on how to make that work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using curly braces to embed your generated message in place, rather than relying on the v-html property.

```
<div>{{parse(message.message)}}
   <i v-if="message.messageTypeId === 2" class="SpecialIcon"></i>
</div>
```